# how to add file pdf in my project

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

How to add file pdf in my project , I use symfony 2 for backend of my project

This is demo of pdf in other project:

[image]

Comment: Exactly what do you mean? To add a file , simply copy it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to store some PDFs on your project, you can create a directory like `web/uploads/docs/` and store your PDFs here.

Then, to show this PDFs on your project, you can use [PDFjs](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/)

Or symply, create a link on your template to this PDF using in the `href` property something like that: `{{ asset('/web/uploads/docs/'your_doc.pdf) }}`

Moreover, if you need to allow users to upload files, you can follow this official guide: http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html